# mat-select in reactive-forms affects the value of mat-radio-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have two material components in a single html file and within the same form. These are done on angular material version 6.0.0

```
    <mat-form-field [hideRequiredMarker]="hideRequired" [floatLabel]="floatLabel" class="mat-form-field-infix">
      <mat-select id="select-status" formControlName="state" required disableOptionCentering>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let status of statuses" [value]="status.value">{{ status.display | translate:{ company_name: (companyName$ | async) } }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

and

```
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="rating">
      <mat-radio-button id="feedback-rating-{{ rating }}" class="feedback-rating" *ngFor="let rating of ratings" [value]="rating">
        {{ rating }}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

When I use them with reactive forms, the selected value of the radio-group is changed to the last value when you touch mat-select even without picking a value. (e.g. if the radio button choices are 1 to 5, 5 would be auto-selected when touching mat-select).  I would assume this is because of reactive forms because when I remove  and formControlName, changing the value of mat-select does not affect the current selected value of mat-ratio-group. This is the initalization of the form

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  state: [null, [Validators.required]],
  rating: [null, [Validators.required]]
});
```

Is there something I missed out? Or has anyone experienced this behavior? If so, what did you do?

edit: the aforementioned behavior does not happen again. It only happens the first time mat-select is touched